# Perl HTTP Request content() issue

Tags: perl

I want to put a file (file.img) as a POST data content, so if the file is in the same folder as the script, is `$req->content(file.img);` valid ?

Cheers

Comment: What is `$req`? Is it a HTTP::Request object?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be something that you could easily test for yourself rather than asking us. What happened when you tried it?

(I'm going to assume that `$req` is an HTTP::Request object - I don't know why you wouldn't include that information in your question).

In short, no, it's not valid. And it's not valid for a number of reasons.

It's not valid because `file.img` would be interpreted as the bareword `file` concatenated with the bareword `img` - which would give the string `fileimg`.

It's not valid because `use strict` makes barewords illegal, so if you're using `use strict` (and you really should be) your code won't even compile.

It's not valid because `HTTP::Request::content` expects a sequence of bytes. So even if you didn't use `use strict` all this code would do would be to add the string `fileimg` to the request body.

If you want to add the contents of the file to the body, then you need to open the file, read in the data and then pass that data to `content`.

This is all explained in the documentation for [HTTP::Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request).